# Access WebService WebMethod from its URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, webmethod

i have this .asmx class:

```
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] 
        public int IsUserAuthorized(String userId, String appId) {

               //returns an int
       }
    }
```

I have the URL where its published : http://soporteapps:100/ControlCenter.asmx (Only works in my jobs LAN)

Then i have an aspx.cs class where i want to display the int that IsUserAuthorized returns:

```
   protected void btnAuth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {           
        String yo = "jcarbajale001";
        String ControlCenter = "4D91B8BF-9D0E-4322-972D-89CC67EC9995";


        ControlCenter.WebService1 service = new WebService1();
        int result = service.IsUserAuthorized(yo, ControlCenter);

        txtBoxWebService.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

This works but its not accesing the URL of the webpage. Its just calling the class and its method, how can i do the same but accesing to the URL of the asmx.

Answer (score 0):

Create a client to consume your webservice and go through it.
You can create it quickly by adding a "service reference"

Comment: Thanks for answering but, could you provide me some example code for more understanding?